# Probability of having $k$ similar elements in two subsets.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a distinct set of elements X and two randomly selected subsets of it $X_1,X_2$ (selected with equal distribution), I would like to find the probability that $|X_1 \cap X_2|\ge m$ where $$0 \le m \le \min{\left(|X_1|,|X_2|\right)}$$
It has been a long time since I have tackled any probability related math problem and I am unsure of how to approach this one. As far as I understand the number of combinations where $|X_1 \cap X_2|=0$ is
$$\dbinom{|X|}{|X_1|}\cdot \dbinom{|X|-|X_1|}{|X_2|}$$
and the number of combinations where $|X_1 \cap X_2|=1$  is
$$\binom{|X|}{|X_1|}\cdot\binom{|X_1|}{1}\cdot \binom{|X|-|X_1|}{|X_2|-1}$$
So I can try to sum up all the combinations and divide them by $$\binom{|X|}{|X_1|}\cdot\binom{|X|}{|X_2|}$$
Is this approach correct? Is there a better one?

I would use this in order to find relations between words in a large text corpus, so I would prefer to avoid unnecessary calculations.

Thanks

Comment: $4^{-n} 3^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}$

Comment: @barrycarter could you explain your answer ?

Comment: Do you mean how I got there or what $n$ and $k$ mean?

Comment: well... both :)

Answer (score 3):

The approach is correct, but you don't need to sum up all the combinations, just $|X_1 \cap X_2| = m$ and those after, all the way till $|X_1 \cap X_2| = min\{|X_1|, |X_2|\}$.

For example the number of combinations where $|X_1 \cap X_2| = m$ is 
$$ \binom{|X|}{|X_1|} \binom{|X_1|}{m} \binom{|X|-|X_1|}{|X_2|-m} $$

Hence the resulting probability should be 
$$ \frac{\sum_{i = m}^{min\{|X_1|, |X_2|\}}\binom{|X|}{|X_1|} \binom{|X_1|}{i} \binom{|X|-|X_1|}{|X_2|-i}}{\binom{|X|}{|X_1|} \binom{|X|}{|X_2|}} $$

Comment: +1. And welcome to math.SE! You could cancel $\binom{|X|}{|X_1|}$. Also, the asymmetry between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is resolved when you write it out in factorials:

$$
\frac{|X_1|!|X_2|!(|X|-|X_1|)!(|X|-|X_2|)!}{|X|!}\sum_{i=m}^{\min\{|X_1|,|X_2|\}}\left((|X_1|-i)!(|X_2|-i)!(|X|-|X_1|-|X_2|+i)!)\right)^{-1}
$$

Comment: BTW, there's a special command `\min` that typesets the operator in roman font -- for other operators without special commands, there's always `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: I believe this simplifies to my answer, could you check?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set with $n$ elements and intersect two randomly 
selected subsets, the probability that the intersection will have 
exactly $k$ elements is: $4^{-n} 3^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}$ (the $4^{-n}$ 
is because there are $4^n$ ways to choose a pair of subsets from $n$ 
elements).

I couldn't actually prove this, but I'm pretty sure it's true and that 
I'm just being lazy. Perhaps someone else could provide a proof?

If you accept the formula above, the mean for a given value of $n$ is 
$\frac{n}{4}$, the variance is $\frac{3 n}{16}$, and the standard 
deviation is thus $\frac{\sqrt{3 n}}{4}$

For large values of $n$, the distribution is essentially normal with 
the parameters above.

Comment: wouldn't $4^n$ mean that you choose two Permutations with repetitions?

Comment: I think you're right. To find this formula, I basically looked at all (2^n)^2 ways of choosing two subsets. Are you saying that, for a given subset S, I shouldn't have counted (S,S) twice? I thought of this problem as randomly selecting one subset and then randomly selecting another. Do you think I've overcounted?