# Probability of Two subsets sharing 2 elements

Tags: probability

It started as a birthday collision but with a twist, we're not colliding birthdays, we're colliding subsets of a larger set of size n, each subset having a size of 3 elements and a successful collision is the event when two subsets share exactly two elements (out of their three), no more no less.

My plan is to use the same model as the standard birthday collision, and just substitute the 1/365 probability with the probability of collision I'm trying to find out now (I hope this would be valid since the new collision is not transitive like the birthday collision).

I had a look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717271/probability-of-having-k-similar-elements-in-two-subsets) and it looks like I can use that answer without the summation and by substituting ***i*** with **2** but I wasn't sure. So here it is:

Let A be a set of elements |A| = n

B  and C are two subsets of A with |B|= |C|= 3

What is the probability that |B ∩ C|= 2 ??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I suspect $B,C$ to be iid and uniformly distributed over the subsets of $A$ that have $3$ elements. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A_3$ denote the collection of subsets of $A$ that have $3$ elements.

Let $B$ be a random set taking values in $\mathcal A_3$ in such a way that the events $\{B=D\}$ for $D\in\mathcal A_3$ are equiprobable.

If $C\in\mathcal A_3$ is **fixed**  then $$P(|B\cap C|=2)=\frac{\binom32\binom{n-3}1}{\binom{n}3}\tag1$$It is like randomly selecting without replacement $3$ elements of $A$ to be the elements of $B$.

This actually is not different if $C$ is a **random** set taking values in $\mathcal A_3$ and independent wrt $B$, so also in that case $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Indeed, B and C are independent and both are randomly built so this would work. Thanks a lot!